# asp.net mvc 2.0 Jquery form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, forms, submit

I am using the following code in my MVC application to login a user. If I get back "1", I redirect user to the dashboard view else login is unsuccessful.

```
  $.post($("form").attr("action"),
                    $("form").serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        if (data == "1")
                            window.location.href = '/dashboard';
                        else
                            $("#result").html('bad username or password');
                    });
```

Is there a better way to do this via the MVC framework such that upon submission of the form, user can be redirected or not based upon login success/failure?

Thanks is  advance for all replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a need to do this via Ajax?  If not then you just do a normal post back to your Controller that handles the post and does a RedirectToAction if successful and returns the View with errors if not.